# Using Variadic Templates to pass arbitary number of variables to function

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a template class which basically allows zero to 3 different types to be used with it. These types are used in the constructor to get values which are later passed to another constructor. Currently, it looks like this (note, code shortened to use 2 params, and remove unneeded code):

```
template<class EditorDialog, typename FirstOpt, typename SecondOpt>
class GenericItemDelegateBase {
public:
    GenericItemDelegateBase( const FirstOpt &first, const SecondOpt &second ) : first( first ), second( second ) {}
protected:
    const FirstOpt first;
    const SecondOpt second;
private:
    EditorDialog *createEditor() const {
        return new EditorDialog( first, second );
    }
};

template<class EditorDialog, typename FirstOpt>
class GenericItemDelegateBase<EditorDialog, FirstOpt, void> {
public:
    GenericItemDelegateBase( const FirstOpt &first ) : first( first ) {}
protected:
    const FirstOpt first;
private:
    EditorDialog *createEditor() const {
        return new EditorDialog( first );
    }
};

template<class EditorDialog>
class GenericItemDelegateBase<EditorDialog, void, void> {
public:
    GenericItemDelegateBase() {}
private:
    EditorDialog *createEditor() const {
        return new EditorDialog();
    }
};

template<class EditorDialog, typename FirstOpt = void, typename SecondOpt = void>
class GenericItemDelegate : public GenericItemDelegateBase<EditorDialog, FirstOpt, SecondOpt> {
public:
    using Base = GenericItemDelegateBase<EditorDialog, FirstOpt, SecondOpt>;
    using Base::Base;
};
```

As you can see, there's a lot of duplication in the code. I was able to remove some of the duplication by using inheritance, and having a `Base` version which has some of the duplicate code (remove in example).

My thought was to try to use variadic templates to allow an arbitrary number of parameters (I picked 3 for this, which has worked so far, but it's possible in the future we may need more). I started to implement this like so:

```
template<class EditorDialog>
class GenericItemDelegate {
    GenericItemDelegate() {}
};

template<class EditorDialog, typename type, typename... args>
class GenericItemDelegate : public GenericItemDelegate<EditorDialog, type, args...> {
    using Base = GenericItemDelegate<EditorDialog, type, args...>;
    GenericItemDelegate( const type &var, args &&... rest ) : Base( std::forward<args>( rest )... ), var( var ) {}
protected:
    const type var;
};
```

The problem I am having, is in this version, I have no idea how to implement the `createEditor` function. It must pass all the variables to the `EditorDialog` constructor, which I am not sure how to do (or if this is even possible).

```
QWidget *createEditor() const {
    return new EditorDialog( [all vars...] );
}
```

I don't know that this is possible with the inheritance structure I have setup, since, depending on the `EditorDialog` being used, it may have a constructor which takes in the three parameters, but not one that takes in only two.

Am I going down the wrong track entirely? Or is it possible to make this work?

Usage examples:

```
int main() {
    auto a = GenericItemDelegate<int>();
    auto b = GenericItemDelegate<int, int>( 3 );
    auto c = GenericItemDelegate<std::vector<int>, int>( 3 );
    auto d = GenericItemDelegate<std::vector<int>, int, std::allocator<int>>( 3, std::allocator<int>() );
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could bring down your example to a [MRE]

Comment: @NutCracker, I added a usage example, but not sure what else you need for an MRE. I could shorten the current code to use no more than 2 params, but I figure the 3 shows more what I'm dealing with... EDIT: shortened.

Comment: I mean try posting some code which can be more easily tested... probably without QT components

Comment: @NutCracker, just just edited to do that :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a std::tuple to store the pack of Opts, then pass in a `std::index_sequence` to make it possible to retrieve them with `std::get`.

Something like so

```
template<class...>
class GenericItemDelegateBase_impl;

template<class EditorDialog, std::size_t... Is, class... Opts>
class GenericItemDelegateBase_impl<EditorDialog, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Opts...> : public QItemDelegate {
public:
    GenericItemDelegateBase_impl( QSqlDatabase &connection, QObject *parent, Opts... opts ) : QItemDelegate( parent ), connection( connection ), m_opts(std::move(opts)...) {}
protected:
    QSqlDatabase connection;
    std::tuple<Opts...> m_opts;
private:
    QWidget *createEditor( QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &, const QModelIndex & ) const override {
        return new EditorDialog( connection, parent, std::get<Is>(m_opts)...);
    }
};

template <class EditorDialog, class... Opts>
using GenericItemDelegateBase = GenericItemDelegateBase_impl<EditorDialog, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Opts)>, Opts...>;
```

Since there are a lot of Qt types in here I havn't tried to compile this, but a part from some possible typos or smaller mistakes it should be ok.

**Edit**
As recommended in the comments, using `std::apply` and a lambda we can simplify the code even further. This requires `c++14` for the use of generic lambdas (auto parameters).

```
#include <tuple>

template<class EditorDialog, class... Opts>
class GenericItemDelegateBase : public QItemDelegate {
public:
    GenericItemDelegateBase( QSqlDatabase &connection, QObject *parent, Opts... opts ) : QItemDelegate( parent ), connection( connection ), m_opts(std::move(opts)...) {}
protected:
    QSqlDatabase connection;
    std::tuple<Opts...> m_opts;
private:
    QWidget *createEditor( QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &, const QModelIndex & ) const override {
        return std::apply([&](auto&&... opts) { return new EditorDialog(connection, parent, opts...); }, m_opts);
    }
};
```

Comment: Looks like you reinvented `std::apply`

Comment: @MSalters You can't call a constructor with `std::apply`. You could use `std::tuple_cat` to add additional parameters to `m_opts` I guess, but this looks cleaner IMO. Not very far from `std::apply`, but also not the same.

Comment: That would be `std::make_from_tuple` :)

Comment: @Quentin Are you sure about that? `std::make_from_tuple` returns by value and in the code there is a dynamic allocation. If you switched to a smart pointer it could work but not here I don't think. [This](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nbTpJoaGg1GePeTA) compiles but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Oops, I guess not... But I think MSalters was suggesting something like `std::apply([](auto &&... opts) { return new EditorDialog(connection, parent, opts...); }, m_opts)`, not to call the constructor directly

Comment: @Quentin That would be cleaner indeed. You could cut away the index_sequence and the parital specialization completely.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your arguments to the `std::tuple` and then pass it into the `EditorDialog` like:

```cpp
template<class EditorDialog, typename ... Args>
class GenericItemDelegateBase {
public:
    GenericItemDelegateBase(Args&&... args)
        : args(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}

protected:
    std::tuple<Args...> args;

private:
    EditorDialog createEditor() const {
        return std::make_from_tuple<EditorDialog>(args);
    }
};
```

And then the following will do the work:

```cpp
auto a = GenericItemDelegateBase<int>();
auto b = GenericItemDelegateBase<int, int>( 3 );
auto c = GenericItemDelegateBase<std::vector<int>, int>( 3 );
auto d = GenericItemDelegateBase<std::vector<int>, int, std::allocator<int>>( 3, std::allocator<int>() );
```

Note that usage of [`std::make_from_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple) requires **C++17**.

**UPDATE**

Since QT requires `createEditor` function to return **pointer**, as suggested by [@MSalters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15416/msalters) in the comments below, you can have:

```cpp
EditorDialog *createEditor() const {
    return new EditorDialog{ std::make_from_tuple<EditorDialog>(args) };
}
```

Comment: When I tried this, it complains my constructors don't take in the correct arguments ...

Comment: Yeah, I tried it on Godbolt for those, and it works. When trying with the Qt classes I have, it fails for those that only have one argument to the constructor (the parent). I modified your code to always have the `QObject *parent` in it. i.e. `return new EditorDialog( parent, args );`, and that's when it fails

Comment: @ChrisMM ok... anyway, I am glad I could help

Comment: Yup. I think it's just how I'm using it, so I'll +1 you anyway. I used super's answer instead though.

Comment: I think you missed a [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) here, that's how you unpack a tuple to be used as function arguments.

Comment: @MSalters `std::apply` can't be used with constructors but i think `std::make_from_tuple` can

Comment: @NutCracker `std::make_from_tuple` uses value sematics though, so you can't do a dynamic allocation and return a pointer with it which seems to be the intent of OP.

Comment: Because this is Qt, the `createEditor` would have to return a pointer

Comment: @NutCracker: You can use `std::make_unique<EditorDialog, Args...>` to wrap the ctor, and then `release()` it so Qt can take over ownership. Alternatively, you'd end up with `return new EditorDialog{std::make_from_tuple<EditorDialog>(args)}`. Relies on guaranteed copy elision, though, as Qt classes can't be copied.

Answer (score 1):

How about different interface and type erasure?

```
template<class EditorDialog>
class GenericItemDelegate
{
    std::function<std::unique_ptr<EditorDialog>()> mFactory;
public:
    template <typename ... Ts>
    GenericItemDelegateBase(Ts... args) :
        mFactory([=](){ return std::make_unique<EditorDialog>(args...); })
    {}
//private:
    EditorDialog* createEditor() const { return mFactory().release(); }
};
```

And then use it as:

```
GenericItemDelegate<int> a;
GenericItemDelegate<int> b(3);
GenericItemDelegate<std::vector<int>> c(3);
GenericItemDelegate<std::vector<int>> d(3, std::allocator<int>());
```

Comment: I might be wrong with how Qt works (which this is for), but I think your solution would cause some errors with it; like prematurely creating the object, and giving it the wrong parent. The `createEditor` actually takes in another parent to pass to the constructor of `EditorDialog`. It would certainly work for the MRE I cut down to though, but I think I cut it down too much.

Comment: @ChrisMM: Object is only in `createEditor`. You have copies of `args` to create the `std::function` (as the others do for the `std::tuple`). *"The createEditor actually takes in another parent to pass to the constructor"*, you might change factory accordingly.

Comment: I didn't see the `function` around the `unique_ptr`, my mistake. Would still need to slightly modify it to work with the `parent`, but that would be easy. Still +1